# How can I scale an object incrementally with Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes, scale

I need to scale the object along Z-axis several times to different values continuously.
Example: start value "0.01" -> second value "10" -> third value "5" -> end value "15".

I managed to make animation nodes only for the first step scale.
Please help me to make nodes for the remaining scale steps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: looks like you've already got  a good approach.  You could use multiple map range nodes, each with different input ranges (0-50) and just add the values together for each leg of the animation.  i.e. a second map-range with input range of 50 to 100 and output range of (0 to -5).  just sum the map range outputs and drive the z scale of your cube that way.

Comment: I am trying to arrange sequence of multiple map range nodes but result is inappropriate. I will be grateful if you can show on the screenshot how this should be arranged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zippy means like this:
[image: Just add the results.]

This is linear, though, and if you want pauses in between you have to adjust the input min-max in each node.

Comment: yep, just that.  i was unable to make a sample earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

AN have `Animate Float` node which let you do this easily.

[image]

If you have large list of data, doing this manually will be hard, in that case we can use loops.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!